# Separating words with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to get this result: 'Summer-is-here'. Why does the code below generate extra spaces? (Current result: '-Summer--Is- -Here-').

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  var newA = str.split(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/).join("-");
  return newA;
}

spinalCase("SummerIs Here");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variety of `split` where the regexp contains a capturing group (inside parentheses), which has a specific meaning, namely to include all the splitting strings in the result. So your result becomes:

```
["", "Summer", "", "Is", " ", "Here", ""]
```

Joining that with `-` gives you the result you see. But you can't just remove the unnecessary capture group from the regexp, because then the split would give you

```
["", "", " ", ""]
```

because you are splitting on zero-width strings, due to the `*` in your regexp. So this doesn't really work.

If you want to use `split`, try splitting on zero-width or space-only matches **looking ahead** to a uppercase letter:

```
> "SummerIs Here".split(/\s*(?=[A-Z])/)
                            ^^^^^^^^^  LOOK-AHEAD
< ["Summer", "Is", "Here"]
```

Now you can join that to get the result you want, but without the lowercase mapping, which you could do with:

```
"SummerIs Here" .
  split(/\s*(?=[A-Z])/) .
  map(function(elt, i) { return i ? elt.toLowerCase() : elt; }) . 
  join('-')
```

which gives you want you want.

Using `replace` as suggested in another answer is also a perfectly viable solution. In terms of best practices, consider the following code from Ember:

```
var DECAMELIZE_REGEXP = /([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g;
var DASHERIZE_REGEXP  = /[ _]/g;

function decamelize(str) {
  return str.replace(DECAMELIZE_REGEXP, '$1_$2').toLowerCase();
}

function dasherize(str) {
  return decamelize(str).replace(DASHERIZE_REGEXP, '-');
}
```

First, `decamelize` puts an underscore `_` in between two-character sequences of lower-case letter (or digit) and upper-case letter. Then, `dasherize` replaces the underscore with a dash. This works perfectly except that it lower-cases the first word in the string. You can sort of combine decamelize and dasherize here with

```
var SPINALIZE_REGEXP = /([a-z\d])\s*([A-Z])/g;

function spinalCase(str) {
  return str.replace(SPINALIZE_REGEXP, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to separate capitalized words, but you are trying to split the string on capitalized words that's why you get those empty strings and spaces.

I think you are looking for this :

```
var newA = str.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g).join("-");
```

Comment: This does not do the lower casing that the OP says he wants.

Comment: @torazaburo : I thought OP's question is : 'Why does the code below generate extra spaces?'. So I said why and gave a solution that doesn't generate extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z][a-z]*) *(?!$|[a-z])
```

You can simply do a replace by `$1-`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL7aZ2/1

```
var re = /([A-Z][a-z]*) *(?!$|[a-z])/g; 
var str = 'SummerIs Here';
var subst = '$1-'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newA = str.split(/ |(?=[A-Z])/).join("-");
```

You can change the regex like:

```
/ |(?=[A-Z])/ or /\s*(?=[A-Z])/
```

Result:

```
Summer-Is-Here
```